# How to maniputlate the size of margins in RTF file

Tags: perl, rtf

I have made a program that takes in an RTF document, sorts it, and then outputs another RTF doc. I have this print statement and I need to manipulate the marigins to make them smaller. I have tried a couple things without success.

```
                if ($_ =~ "ERROR"){
                $rtf->prolog(
                'title' => "Color Test", 
                'colors' => [ 
                undef,       
                [0,0,0],     # 1 - black
                [255,0,0],   # 2-red
                [0,255,0],   # 3-green
                [0,0,255],   # 4-blue
                [255,128,0], # 5-orange
                [255,255,0], # 6-yellow
                ],
                );
        #PRINT ERRORS IN RED        
                $rtf->printf( \'{\fs20\lang1036\noproof\cf2\highlight1  %s} \par ', "$_");

        }
```

I read that the command is marglN and margrN but I have not been successful in using these. Any ideas?

Comment: Aren't there various querying methods in those `RTF` modules?  You shouldn't have (or want) to use a separate tool like `Data::Dumper` in order to look at content.

Comment: Yes they are I didn't think about that. But when i use `$writer` it does the same thing.

Comment: OK -- read the docs.  This is the basic use, it's got to be explained.  (I don't use this module so I can't say how to do it, but the important "answer" here is that you look through documentation.)

Comment: *"I am trying to take in an input file in RTF and output as an RTF file"* That sounds like you want to want to just *copy* the file, in which case you can use `File::Copy`. If you want something different from that then please be more precise about what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Eventually I will need to sort the input file and then output it to a separate file.

Comment: @mdavies23: Okay, but exactly what question are you trying to get answered with this post? Do you simply need to copy the file?

Comment: @Borodin: I have an input file with "Apples" in RTF and want to get it into a different file named output.rtf with the same formatting. But not just simply copying because in the future i need to be able to sort a long input file

Comment: @mdavies23: So you want to copy the information from one RTF file to another RTF file, but changed somehow to facilitate sorting? What sort of changes do you have in mind?

Comment: @Borodin: Basically i have the code set up now where i input Apples in blue font. I want it to be written to the output file as Apples in blue font. In the future I want to have a list "Apples, Bananas, Strawberries" and sort it and only output lets say "Apples" and keep its original formatting.

Answer (score 1):

In the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/RTF::Tokenizer#get_token):

```
my ( $type, $argument, $param ) = get_token();
```

$type is one of `text`, `control`, `group`, `escape` or `eof`.
I'm guessing you're interested in the text tokens.

the entry for text says: $argument contains the actual text.

So I would suggest trying:

```
for my $token ( @tokens ){
    my ( $type, $arg ) = @$token;
    next unless $type eq 'text';
    print "$arg\n";
}
```

This code is untested.